# SQLite: ResultSet returning SQLException

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have the following database `ShorthandText`

```
textid | text
-------------------------- 
1      | just a test
2      | just another test
```

I am using the following code to try return the two Strings in the `text` column

```
public List<String> executeSQLWithMulipleReturns(String sql) throws SQLException{
    List<String> results = null;
    connection = ConnectDb();
    stat = connection.createStatement();
    resultSet = stat.executeQuery(sql); // sql = "SELECT text FROM ShorthandText;"
    while(resultSet.next()){
        results.add(resultSet.getString(resultSet.getRow()));
        System.out.println(resultSet.toString());
    }

    closeAll(); // closes all connections         
    return results;
}
```

But am getting the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: column 2 out of bounds [1,1]
at org.sqlite.RS.checkCol(RS.java:64)
at org.sqlite.RS.markCol(RS.java:71)
at org.sqlite.RS.getString(RS.java:245)
at Java.ConnectToDatabase.executeSQLWithMulipleReturns(ConnectToDatabase.java:46)
at GUI.ShorthandText.jButton1ActionPerformed(ShorthandText.java:123)
at GUI.ShorthandText.access$000(ShorthandText.java:18)
at GUI.ShorthandText$2.actionPerformed(ShorthandText.java:82)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
......
```

which occurs on this line: `results.add(resultSet.getString(resultSet.getRow()));`

Can anyone please explain why I am getting this error?

**EDIT: Null pointer exception**

code

```
while(resultSet.next()){
        results.add(resultSet.getString("text"));
        System.out.println(resultSet.toString());
    }

while(resultSet.next()){
        results.add(resultSet.getString(1));
        System.out.println(resultSet.toString());
    }
```

both give this exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Java.ConnectToDatabase.executeSQLWithMulipleReturns(ConnectToDatabase.java:46)
at GUI.ShorthandText.jButton1ActionPerformed(ShorthandText.java:123)
at GUI.ShorthandText.access$000(ShorthandText.java:18)
at GUI.ShorthandText$2.actionPerformed(ShorthandText.java:82)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
.......
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is here:

```
results.add(resultSet.getString(resultSet.getRow()));
```

[`resultSet.getString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29) gets as parameter the column index, but you are passing `resultSet.getRow()`

if you want to get the ids into `results`, you should use:

```
results.add(resultSet.getString("textid"));
```

or

```
results.add(resultSet.getString(0));
```

if you want to get the texts into `results`, you should use:

```
results.add(resultSet.getString("text"));
```

or

```
results.add(resultSet.getString(1));
```

**Update**

Oh, my, that's so simple! You had actually two problems. We already solved the first one. Here's your second problem:

```
List<String> results = null;
```

The `List<String> results` has not been initialized, thus, the `NullPointerException`.'This line should be:

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This will take care of it.

Comment: but if i try something like 'results.add(resultSet.getString(1));' I get a null pointer exception even though there is data in the database?

Comment: I have tried this also but it also gives me a null pointer exception... i will add this to an edit of my answer

Comment: i have tried both these ways before i came here and both give the exception in my edit... which keeps leading me to believe that there is no fields in the database but i have checked this numerous times and they are there

Comment: @HipHipArray: If you read next() method description from Javadoc, it is vendor dependent, I strongly feel, what ever the database driver you are using not supporting next() method.

Comment: @Adrian: That was it alright, results had not been initialized... should have caught that myself but kept thinking twas something with my database itself :-S thank for all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

getRow returns the number of the row within the resultset

You have a one column result set

First iteration of `results.add(resultSet.getString(resultSet.getRow()));` with call getString with an index of 1 ( and will work )

Second iteration of `results.add(resultSet.getString(resultSet.getRow()));` with call getString with an index of 2 ( and will fail as there is only one column in the result set )

I think you should be doing `results.add(resultSet.getString(1));`

You want the first item out of the result set each time you read from it.